# Were the aliens from Pitch Black a bio-weapon?

Tags: riddick-franchise, pitch-black

A species reacting so badly to sunlight seems unlikely to have evolved on a planet with continual sunlight. Furthermore, the planet seems to have had large animals at one point in the past, but has been stripped bare, presumably by the monsters.

Sounds like a bio-weapon to me. Perhaps the planet was involved in a war? I know that there is some extended stuff with Pitch Black...was there ever any discussion of this?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is doubtful. A planet that receives perpetual sunlight for twenty two years followed by a month of darkness implies a solar system with a complex configuration (similar to Asimov's [Nightfall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightfall_%28Asimov_short_story_and_novel%29)). Such systems are not as stable as the sort of solar system that we live in. Some time in the past, *after the creatures evolved*, the system must have gone through some form of orbital perturbation resulting in the current seasonal cycles.

During the first month of darkness, the creatures very likely devoured everything that the lack of sunlight didn't already kill. After this, the creatures adapted from being daily nocturnal predators to being predators that hibernate between periods of darkness and then wake up extremely cranky.

It is very doubtful that someone would engineer a bio-weapon with two glaring weaknesses -- inability to tolerate even a flashlight and a blind spot smack at the center of its field of vision.

Comment: Reminds of of Nuclear Man (2nd) from Superman IV: The Quest for Peace. He can only fight in daylight.

Comment: They aren't hibernating, they're subterranean. They're also cannibals. Toss in blindness and a weakness to flashlights and they really are the world's worst biological weapon. Like something Prof. Farnsworth would slap together.

Comment: My mistake. But I'm thinking they *must* have been hibernating for much of the 22 years. Without the sun, nothing will grow underground, and without a net energy input, cannibalism won't work indefinitely.

Comment: @HNL many subterranean critters eat the roots of plants. If the PB nasties ate something like that...

Comment: Well, my thinking with the whole bio-weapon thing is that those weaknesses allow the weapon to be controlled. And that would make it the perfect weapon to deploy right as night was falling, and then come back a month later and occupy the ruins.

Comment: Your thinking Chris is more devious and military-minded than you might realize. As a former military operative, I would happen to agree with you. These creatures could not have evolved on this world. Evolution takes more time than this planet appears to have left. It would only take a few more sunsets and they will eat each other into extinction.

Answer (score 16):

**In the canon notes for the movie, Pitch Black, the alien creatures were just there. No explanation is given. The movie is a film about survival and what a person might do to survive. With that out of the way, let's speculate on whether the creatures could actually BE bio-engineered weapons of mass destruction.**

### **What makes a good bio-weapon, anyway?**

What makes a good bio-weapon, especially if your targets are human, space-faring, and perhaps not always as well armed as modern humans are today? You want your bio-weapon to be:

- Fear-causing, first-striking, and mysterious appearing to humans
- Strong, fast and aggressive, difficult to drive away. Strong hunting instincts so that the creature seeks the target as fast as possible.
- Durable or plentiful. In an ideal world, both.
- Well adapted to its environment, giving it an advantage especially against humans. The ability to work in low-light conditions gives the weapons an advantage against human populations.
- High level of maneuverability, including flight
- Just enough intelligence to make them tenacious seeking prey
- Able to be transported, perhaps it hibernates or has a dormant state which can be triggered artificially.

### **The care and feeding of your bio-weapon**

Yet you would want an easy means of controlling or destroying your bio-weapon once its done its job. Or worse you just want to make a planet a wasteland, scorching it and making a government have to gather resources to reclaim its planet. They also make fine shock troops for night attacks and night operations.

- light vulnerability make sense if you wanted to make it possible to reclaim areas where the creature has spread
- You could reclaim  territory after the targets or other life-forms are destroyed, have a trained and prepared reclamation teams who know all the weaknesses of the creatures.
- Who among the normal population would think a flashlight might be able to temporarily deter the creatures? Bomb their local powerplant, turn off the lights, unleash your beasties after sunset, and let them go to work!

### **Who would you use your bio-weapon on?**

With these parameters, I could see an excellent reason for considering them a bio-weapon. But what would you target with such a weapon? A trick question:

- unarmed or lightly-armed populations with longer darkness periods
- populations on planetary moons with unusual or erratic rotations or periods of darkness
- underground populations (negates movement advantages) but allows sonar to work just fine.

### **But where would you test such a weapon?**

A rogue moon, off the beaten path, with no people, but a thriving ecosystem. (Sound familiar, yet?) Unleash the creatures, study the results, leave the creatures to starve once the tests are done. You don't tell anyone where you do this work and if a survey team happens to blunder onto your test area and doesn't report this, or if the creatures don't die on schedule, there might be unfortunate, unreported accidents...

Answer (score 11):

I don't know about biological weapons, but from an evolutionary point of view they seem pretty unlikely. No species could survive by eating every living thing in an ecosystem (in this case, the entire planet) without leaving some species of prey behind to reproduce to provide more prey. As for the roots of plants: a) there do not appear to be any plants on the planet, and b) the aliens' teeth and jaws are obviously carnivorous. Cannibalism, as HNL says, cannot work indefinitely as the 'trade-off' between the energy used to reproduce and the energy gained from eating offspring does not add up.
Good film though ;)

Comment: +1 From an evolutionary standpoint, these creatures don't make sense. They would have been extinct without getting the chance to evolve any survival traits. A planetary change so big would simply have killed them all, along with all the other lifeforms.

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe it is a bio weapon. The bone yard and signs of a once thriving ecostystem makes it seem like it all died suddenly which supports a sudden change (like the species showing up there) suggests it did not evolve there. However it does not mean it did not evolve somewhere else that did not have any sunlight or very little like pluto (i know not a planet) where the sun is more like a star in the   sky.http://astrobob.areavoices.com/2012/01/05/what-would-the-sun-look-like-from-jupiter-or-pluto/
It could then be introduced to the ecostystem from a ship burrow under ground to escape the sun and repoduce feeding on the underground ecostystem and capturing life from above, as seen when they were digging in the movie until the planet had its long night when it could really feed and grow. It may have taken a few hundred years (still sudden from a planet's standpoint) for them to reach the numbers required to end almost all life on the planet, but could be done in 4 or 5 long nights on the planet (ie every 22 years night comes and lasts ??? a month or 2 ??? so 4-5 times is over 100 years) as there are no natural predators and no or very little need for canabalism when the planet is full of life leaving them to grow unchecked. They could still be there suffering from diminishing returns(ie. eating there own to repoduce). Or surive from surviving remains of the old ecostystem one component being the glow worms.

```
  So in conclusion I believe they are not bioweapons but a foreign species.
```

Answer (score 1):

Pitch Black takes place in a universe where space flight is normal in every way. The abandoned camp that the protagonists find is a mining outpoust... this says to me that space flight is so completely boring and easy that they'll fly to other planets just to grab heavy ores and minerals and take them somewhere else.

Furthermore, if there are any quarantine procedures that are required to be performed by regulatory agencies, we never see a hint of this either in the original or in the sequel.

A creature such as the Pitch Black nasties could easily stow away in some barely-pressurized cargo hold. Only to emerge on the Pitch Black world somewhere or at a certain time where it could complete a burrow to hide.

I don't think it's an engineered creature. It might be *used* as a bioweapon, but it is probably an evolved species. If it were a bioweapon, why not cook in a few genes to turn it off after 5 years? These things set up a colony on that planet, after all, and were surviving underground for over 20 years. The only bioweapon that you'd let live that long would be a doomsday device. It'd take them what, less than a year or two to kill the biosphere of the planet? Even less to kill the sapient inhabitants. Definitely need some Monsanto Terminator-seed genes in the damned things.

It's not a bioweapon, just an argument for sane quarantine procedures for explorers.

Answer (score 0):

No I don't think they were bio-weapons I believe they were there from the beginning. Sure every living thing ( save the glow worms) has been wiped out on the surface but we are never shown how extensive the subterranean portion of the planet is. There might be a whole other thriving ecosystem under the surface capable of sustaining the creature, maybe even keep them in check with a bigger more aggressive species. Through out the whole movie we only see but a few miles of the entire planet and this know next to nothing about its complete makeup. These creature could live on a hive environment like ants or wasps and the survivors just happen to crash next to one of these hives. So in short I think the movie does not give a fair, complete picture of the planet and so we can not claim fact on anything just theories; and this one is mine.